# Good book introducing Inconics

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, conic-sections, book-recommendation, projective-geometry

### General Requirements

- Book
- Conic Sections
- Triange Geometry
- Inconics of Triangle

### Ideal Topics

- Projective properties arising from inconics like collinearity/concurrency relationships
- Other basic properties (e.g. foci are isogonal conjugates)
- Important points corresponding to inconics (e.g. Brianchon Point)
- Special inconics
- Equations in various angular or linear coordinate systems (e.g. Trilinear Coordinates, Barycentric Coordinates)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the most celebrated of the old books in English is Salmon's *Treatise on Conics*. An earlier answer has download links to that and some other 19th century English analytical geometry texts:

[Good books on conic section.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358019/good-books-on-conic-section/358037#358037)

Another place to look is volume 2 of H.F. Baker's treatise, http://archive.org/details/principlesofgeom02bake .

I don't think that most of the subjects listed in the question are necessarily covered in those books, but they would contain most of the classical facts, especially if supplemented with a detailed enough source on projective geometry.

---

More: following the comment link at an earlier question ( [Existence of Gergonne point, without Ceva theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320779/existence-of-gergonne-point-without-ceva-theorem#comment721762_320840) ) and looking on MathWorld leads to some references related to the question.  Smith, *Geometrical Conics* seems closest to what you are asking (of the books) and there are some journal articles.

Answer (score 1):

Veblen & Young Projective geometry series covers this but I am not sure if it is in depth enough for you.